# Formating the display of a post's date, outside the Loop

Tags: formatting, date-time, loop

I'm using this function to be able to retrieve several data, from outside the Loop:

```
function get_post_data($postId) {
 global $wpdb;
 return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=$postId");
}
```

... and then, this to display the date a post was published:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;
global $thePostID;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
$data = get_post_data($thePostID);
echo $data[0]->post_date;
?>
```

wich displays something like "2010-06-14 22:36:03" in my sidebar, but I'd like to format it like just "June, 2010"

Can it be done?

Comment: Not related to your question, but check out [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function that is native and more reliable way to retrieve single post's data.

Comment: Agree with Rarst, why create a function for it when one exists already.. use `get_post()` or even `get_posts()` with `posts_per_page` set to 1 and `nopaging` set to true (it offers a little more than the singular counterpart).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using something like this:

```
date('F, Y', strtotime($data[0]->post_date));
```

Comment: Thanks!To clarify for the readers, it worked when "echoed" it